# Facing issues while building project with gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a simple gradle project, where the build.gradle is as follow:

```
// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java-library'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
 }

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Now while I am running gradle build I am getting an error as :

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
>     Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s

Full stacktrace is as follow :

```
    Exception is:
    org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
        at 
    org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:857)
        at 
    org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:808)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:612)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:807)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:612)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:807)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:612)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:322)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:316)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.doNewInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.newInstance(DefaultGradleLauncherFactory.java:106)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    Caused by: org.gradle.internal.service.ServiceCreationException: Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:857)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:808)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:612)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:807)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:612)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:807)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:612)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.assembleParameters(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:821)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryService.create(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:807)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$ManagedObjectServiceProvider.getInstance(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:612)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$SingletonService.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:669)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:322)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry.get(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:316)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.defaultScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:301)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory(BuildScopeServices.java:293)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:855)
        ... 60 more
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\gradlePipeline\.gradle\4.5\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock (Access is denied)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:103)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.incrementLockCount(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:105)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.acquireFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:161)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.onStartWork(DefaultCacheAccess.java:368)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:213)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:203)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:298)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.newCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:57)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.createCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:148)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.createCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:177)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CrossBuildFileHashCache.createCache(CrossBuildFileHashCache.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CachingFileHasher.<init>(CachingFileHasher.java:44)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter(BuildSessionScopeServices.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.invoke(ReflectionBasedServiceMethod.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.service.DefaultServiceRegistry$FactoryMethodService.invokeMethod(DefaultServiceRegistry.java:855)
        ... 82 more
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\gradlePipeline\.gradle\4.5\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock (Access is denied)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.filelock.LockFileAccess.<init>(LockFileAccess.java:33)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager$DefaultFileLock.<init>(DefaultFileLockManager.java:149)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:100)
        ... 97 more
```

I am not very experienced with gradle. Can you please give me a bit insight what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is better to use gradle wrapper `./gradlew` if you are starting new project.
https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: Did you do what it says to do to debug this? *Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.*? **If so show the output, if not then do that before you waste any more of peoples time guessing for you.**

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: I have added full stacktrace.

Comment: Looks like you have a `ACCESS` related issue, please check!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your stacktrace there is the line

`Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\gradlePipeline\.gradle\4.5\fileHashes\fileHashes.lock (Access is denied)`

So I'm going to assume you've put your Jenkins workspace into your program files directory, and running your build from a non-elevated process, which means it cannot write into the program files.

Configure your Jenkins slave to put the workspace into a directory where it has write access.